# How can I pick out July month of this ime series (runoff) to plot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How can I pick out just July-month of these time series? My time series goes from 1985-2018 with runoff values on the right side. I need to get some help with further code to pick out the July-values and then plot it. 
my code:

from pandas import read_csv

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os

import cartopy

from datetime import date,datetime

dir1 = "mystiations/"

files = os.listdir(dir1)

files = np.sort(files)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.txt_')]

df = pd.read_csv(dir1+files_txt[0],skiprows=6,header=None, index_col=0,sep=" ",na_values=-9999)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M")
parse_dates=True

index_col=0

myperiod = df["1985":"2018"]

myperiod

[runoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88LF.png)

Comment: Paste your code in text format not an image

Comment: i have posted my code now